# c# winforms application reinstall in other than administrator user accounts

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, installation

I have created a setup project and have validations in it from installerClass,i installed the application in one system using the administrator user account,after installed successfully ,i just log off the system and login as normal user account,and i clicked the shortcut icon from the desktop for my application (installed from admin account) it again stating the installation.
I don't need to reinstall it,(it not possible to allow the reinstall in another account validation failed) how to restrict this.

Comment: Can you clarify a couple of things. a) Is this a click once or a standard MSI installer? b) your not clicking the shortcut to install again are you? you are definitely clicking the installed app's shortcut icon? c) are you installing for `Everyone`?

Comment: a)MSI installer.b)No ,i am clicking the installed applicatio's shotcut
c)Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it from another link says "non-advertised" shortcuts with DISABLEADVTSHORTCUTS=1.
I use the orca application to edit the properties of .msi file.
if you are using win xp u can found the orca in your sytem path:C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Bin\Orca.msi install it and edit Created msi using the Select 
Properies from left panel-> right click on right panel ->add row->Name as DISABLEADVTSHORTCUTS ,value as 1. save.